# Data rate explained

Tags: video, properties

If you go to the properties of a video file (specifically an MP4), under details, under video, it gives a 'data rate'. What does this mean?

I had a 14 min vid, which I cut down to a 8 min video (using the programme Handbrake). It lowered the file size significantly from 897MB to 160MB, but the 'data rate' also changed from 8807kbps to 2717kbps. What does this tell us about the video?

Answer (score 1):

It tells us that the video has been re-encoded using less storage - so quite probably that it is of lower quality then the original.

The data rate is the speed with which it fills up disk - or how much bandwidth would be required to stream the video.  Of-course, different codecs and options can provide better / worse quality for a given amount of disk, but as a very general rule, the lower the data rate the more visual information is lost, and the less accurate the picture will look compared to the original.